# Fast way to get Expression method call target

Tags: c#, performance, delegates, expression, dynamic-invoke

Given the following code line of code,

```
Expression<Action> expression = () => target.ToString();
```

**is there a *fast* way to obtain the `target` object?**

Below code works

```
public object GetExpressionTarget<T>(Expression<T> expression)
{
    MethodCallExpression methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) expression.Body;
    LambdaExpression theTarget = Expression.Lambda(methodCall.Object, null);
    Delegate compiled = theTarget.Compile();

    return compiled.DynamicInvoke();    }
```

but is very, very slow.

---

Is there a faster way to get the target of a method call expression?

---

Benchmarking my code (`GetDelegate`, `DelegateCompile` and `DelegateDynamicInvoke`) as well as @IvanStoev's code (`GetFunc`, `FuncCompile` and `FuncInvoke`) yields this result:

```
|                Method |           Mean |         Error |        StdDev |
|---------------------- |----------------|---------------|---------------|
|       DelegateCompile | 165,068.477 ns | 2,671.3001 ns | 2,498.7358 ns |
|           FuncCompile | 160,956.199 ns | 2,133.5343 ns | 1,995.7093 ns |
| DelegateDynamicInvoke |   1,148.191 ns |    11.7213 ns |    10.9642 ns |
|            FuncInvoke |       3.040 ns |     0.0264 ns |     0.0247 ns |
```

So, `Invoke` is actually quite faster than `DynamicInvoke`, but the bottleneck is actually the `Compile` call. Is there a way to get the `target` object without having to compile expressions?

Benchmark code:

```
public class Program
{
    private Delegate @delegate;
    private Func<object> func;

    private static Delegate GetDelegate(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) expression.Body;
        return Expression.Lambda(methodCall.Object, null).Compile();
    }

    private static Func<object> GetFunc(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) expression.Body;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(methodCall.Object).Compile();
    }

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        object o = new object();
        Expression<Action> expression = () => o.ToString();

        this.@delegate = Program.GetDelegate(expression);
        this.func = Program.GetFunc(expression);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void DelegateCompile()
    {
        object o = new object();
        Expression<Action> expression = () => o.ToString();

        Program.GetDelegate(expression);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FuncCompile()
    {
        object o = new object();
        Expression<Action> expression = () => o.ToString();

        Program.GetFunc(expression);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void DelegateDynamicInvoke()
    {
        this.@delegate.DynamicInvoke();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FuncInvoke()
    {
        this.func.Invoke();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `Compile` is the slowest part, but how about `Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(methodCall.Object).Compile().Invoke()`

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for your idea, but sadly this does not improve performance either. Benchmarks showed `187 us` for the code in my question, and `195 us` for your proposed code (which isn't much worse, but it's not what I hoped for).

Comment: Did you separate `Compile()` from `Invoke()` when measuring (like in the code in question)? Or you are measuring the whole method? At least you can see if there is a difference between `DynamicInvoke` and `Invoke`. I still believe the slowest part is the `Compile()` method, not the invocation (one or another way).

Comment: @IvanStoev please see the edits. You're right that `Compile` actually is the slowest part. Also, your approach is quite faster than using `DynamicInvoke`, but as it uses `Compile`, it is still very slow. Thank you for your help nevertheless

Comment: It should say "the bounty-winning **answer** would optimally propose code that works (quite) faster than the code in the question" of course...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I can think of to avoid the time costly `Compile` operation is to evaluate the expression content recursively using reflection.

Doing this generically (handling all the cases) is a complicated task. Currently there are more than 80 [ExpressionType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressiontype?view=netframework-4.7.2)s, all of them with different semantics (well, some fall into categories with corresponding base classes). In order to handle them all, one should probably create custom [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) and implement evaluation engine (probably with some sort of an evaluation stack).

In other words, a lot of work/code.

However... If we limit the expressions to 2 types - [ConstantExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2) (constant value) and [MemberExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2) (field or property of a constant value), then there is a relatively easy solution. The method in question already contains assumption about the passed `Expression<Action>` and the sample expression target (which is a closure) falls into constant value field category.

The main work is done in a private recursive method as follows:

```
static object Evaluate(Expression expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
        return null;
    if (expression is ConstantExpression constExpression)
        return constExpression.Value;
    if (expression is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        var target = Evaluate(memberExpression.Expression);
        if (memberExpression.Member is FieldInfo field)
            return field.GetValue(target);
        if (memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo property)
            return property.GetValue(target);
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

and the method in question using it would be

```
public object GetExpressionTarget<T>(Expression<T> expression)
{
    var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
    return Evaluate(methodCall.Object);
}
```

I have no performance comparison results, but even though this is using reflection, it should be much faster than the `Compile` which uses reflection *and* dynamic IL code emit, not counting creation of a `DynamicMethod` and delegate for invoking it.

Comment: Ivan, thank you so much for your answer. The code works great for my use case, and is much faster than the code in the question - `1,600 ns` compared to `160,000 ns`. Thank you not only for giving code that does the task, but also for explaining how to write code for all the expression types. You really deserve the bounty :)

Comment: i started writing this after seeing how Compile is the slowest thing ever and thenw as like, i bet someone already did this for me!.  You should expand to include MethodCallExpression

Answer (score 1):

i've expanded on Ivan's solution a bit as time has gone on in case it helps anyone else

```
        static object Evaluate(
            Expression expression
        )
        {
            switch (expression)
            {
                case ConstantExpression e:
                    return e.Value;

                case MemberExpression e when e.Member is FieldInfo field:
                    return field.GetValue(
                        Evaluate(
                            e.Expression
                        )
                    );

                case MemberExpression e when e.Member is PropertyInfo property:
                    return property.GetValue(
                        Evaluate(
                            e.Expression
                        )
                    );

                case ListInitExpression e when e.NewExpression.Arguments.Count() == 0:
                    var collection = e.NewExpression.Constructor.Invoke(new object[0]);
                    foreach(var i in e.Initializers)
                    {
                        i.AddMethod.Invoke(
                            collection,
                            i.Arguments
                                .Select(
                                    a => Evaluate(a)
                                )
                                .ToArray()
                        );
                    }
                    return collection;

                case MethodCallExpression e:
                    return e.Method.Invoke(
                        Evaluate(e.Object),
                        e.Arguments
                            .Select(
                                a => Evaluate(a)
                            )
                            .ToArray()
                    );

                default:
                    //TODO: better messaging
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

        }
```